# How to route all traffic to a specific ip

Tags: router, routing

I own an Aztech 5005EN modem and I want to route all packets/requests to a local web server. When clients who connected to the router try to open a website, they should get the special page.

In this example my default gateway is 192.168.2.1 and I want to route all traffic to 192.168.2.2

I tried using *network->routing* with the following information but nothing happened.

- destination IP : 192.168.2.2
- network mask : 255.255.255.0 -> i dont know about this
- gateway : 192.168.2.1
- interface : PVC0
- metric : 1

This is a screen shot of my routing page in my router

[image]

Comment: It sounded like what you want is a feature called Captive Portal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal). You don't want to route traffic. You want to redirect traffic to a new destination. There are various ways to implement it. The best way requires the help of router (since devices cannot bypass it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static route on the PC.

Open cmd with Admin rights:

`route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.2`. This will make the PC to send all the traffic to `192.168.2.2`. Make sure to have a internet via `192.168.2.2`

Comment: thanks for the answer.but i need it for all people who are connected to the router.not just me!

Comment: Add the route on call the machines. I don't think the router which you are using is capable of doing reverse route injection.

Comment: "Add the route on call the machines"?can you explain?

Comment: Adding the above route on all computers manually will fix this issue. Copy paste the same code on all machines.